# What makes my question a real question?

Tags: discussion, closing

Hi, I (not really) asked about [interesting bugs which are messing up game logic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4433/hilarious-bugs-messing-up-game-logic-closed).
For me it's interesting or funny to see what scenarios developer did not think about.

I can't see a difference of question-quality to several game-recs or on Stackoverflow questions about bad design.

Please explain the quality-difference.

update:
The special value of my question is that I can not get the answer from my Amazon-reccomendation, or simply from a walkthrough.

Bonus-question:
Sorry for sarcasm:
If I called my question "Games that have bugs which mess up game-logic" would it not have been closed? It's a game-rec question so it would have been controverse *but* legal.

I see that questions which demand list-answers are not appreciated, but then you should at least be consistent.

Comment: Some related reading ♪ http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/475/best-favourite-subjective-list-type-questions and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/624/re-evaluating-our-site-what-is-the-scope-of-an-acceptable-list-if-it-exists

Comment: The topic of game-recs are heavily under debate, so that's not a good point of comparison.

Comment: The goal of consistency is entirely why I asked the "Re-evaluating our site" question in the first place. Inconsistency is *really harmful* to our site's life. I urge you to review what people have contributed, perhaps throw in your own answer or comment on what others have had to say, and help us create the consistency that we will need.

Comment: Your "loophole" for getting the question in is exactly the kind of reasoning which has made me come to dislike recommendation questions. Speaking on substance, it is no different than other questions asking for a list of games with a specific feature, like, say, a certain style of costume design.

Answer (score 4):

First, I wouldn't refer to other questions to justify a particular one, those questions will be debated separately and closed if necessary.

So, let's analyse your question based only on its content, have you read the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)?

It's not a matter of quality, it's just that for me (and the people that voted to close it) it doesn't conform to the category of questions that are allowed.

> #### What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

Do you think it falls under the category of allowed questions?

Keep in mind that we are in beta and continuously improving, and that if 5 people agree that it's a good question, they can vote to re-open it!

Comment: My question is neither subjective nor argumentatic, or requires discussion.
Either a bug takes influence on game logic or not.

Comment: @eL13 It's the last sentence that's the important point, though it could use some better phrasing. "questions that can be answered" is more accurately questions that can be solved - that there exists a potential conclusion to the question. None of the answers you will receive on your question are 'solutions' because there is nothing to solve, they're just 'responses'. This is why list questions are very much in dispute, since they tend to counteract this requirement. That's my stance, at any rate.

Comment: Thanks, this has much more content than your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's asking for a list, not an answer. How can you say an answer is the **right** answer with that question?

You can't. Which is why game-rec is controversial. Some can be answered, some could have a list of every game ever made.

Comment: My question was, to explain the _difference_ - sorry, probably I'm too dumb to understand this :(

Comment: The difference is that there is no right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

"For me it's interesting or funny to see what scenarios developer did not think about."

This is exactly the problem. The question was asked for your own amusement, not because it was a question that you needed to have answered. Controversial as game-rec may be, it's based off of a need for a new game under some criteria, not off of a desire for funny stories.

Comment: I'd argue that there's just as much potential for game recommendations based purely on a desire for amusement. Motivation behind answering the question can be important for determining the nature of the real question, but it is that nature of the real question that is what we should judge on, not why the person asked. It should be no different than if I asked the same question about bugs in games because I was doing a research paper on it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry about that.

Comment: My intention is not relevant, as long as my question is relevant.